# Using dynamic allocations in a mission-critical / life-critical software

Tags: c++

Is it safe to use dynamic allocations in a mission-critical / life-critical system, or should it be avoided?

Comment: mission critical != life critical.

Comment: It is a matter of timing, don't allocate while the X-ray machine delivers the dose.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25

Comment: To expand on GregS:  Mission-critical means something important fails if the software doesn't work.  It doesn't necessarily imply real-time.  Life-critical means somebody is likely to die of software failure or its immediate and direct consequence, and typically is real-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With critical software you want your system to have as deterministic behaviour as possible.

Dynamic memory, memory fragmentation, possible leaks, and in some corner cases (not too rare) misbehaviour of malloc will make it that much harder to gain 100% determinism.

That said, if part of your program (say an algorithm) requires dynamic allocation and you can **prove** that your memory allocation and de-allocation (free) will be deterministic (see valuable notes by RickNZ) then you're closer to having a deterministic system.

Answer (score 8):

If you are writing this sort of software you ought to have a big book for the specification you are conforming to (FAA, NATO, FDA, whatever) of what you can and cannot do, and it will tell you.

In general, however; no, since the systems you describe are very hard to prove correct. Although in life critical software normally there has to be **hardware** responsible to restarting the software if an error condition is signalled (ie, a watchdog timer that the software has to reset evert 100ms to prevent a hardware reset)

Comment: And if I'm writing this book?

Comment: If you have to ask this question here, then you shouldn't be.

Comment: Oh! Then you probably ought to know better than most people who will answer this question :) I would say no: don't allow dynamic allocation. Memory is so cheap that large static buffers ought to suffice.

Comment: It's not just life-critical that use watchdog timers--many embedded systems do too. I've worked on automotive engine controls and they use both a watchdog and a limp-home-mode if the watchdog triggers too often.

Comment: @Neil: Asking questions to gather more input is rarely a bad thing. If a specification is written by someone who *thinks* he/she knows all the answers and doesn't bother to see what others think, then it will be a poor specification indeed.

Comment: @MarkW I think someone capable of writing such a standards document would be asking less naive and more specific questions.

Comment: In life critical applications, it is better to kill the machine than the patient.

Comment: @MarkW:  A specification should be written for something specific.  "Mission-critical/life-critical" is not a good description.  A question like "when, if ever, should dynamic allocation take place in a software-controlled X-ray machine" would be more promising.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: Sometimes. But your design document should include the proof for that. If there are other critical patients that also need that particular machine, and the failure is certainly transient, you either kill the current patient or the machine and some future patients. (Consider space flight)

Answer (score 4):

One approach I've used when I can't completely avoid dynamic allocation in "can't fail" type applications is to allocate the buffers and other data structures I need only once, when the app first starts -- so they never need to be freed.  It's loops and frees/deletes that don't correspond with news/allocs that tend to cause problems...

When that's not enough, another trick I've used is to run with my own custom version of malloc and free, with code that takes special care to check for common error conditions, like freeing something that's already been freed, regularly verifying freelist pointer integrity, looking to see if total memory use is increasing over time, etc.

Answer (score 3):

All the trading systems and other banking software I've ever worked on use dynamic allocation very heavily, and they are mission critical for the IBs that use them. I prefer to avoid working on life-critical systems, so can't speak for them.

Answer (score 0):

Better avoid it. The smallest memory leak in your system will with time make your system crash. For example life critical system like car and air plane do not use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Not all leaks are memory leaks.

Comment: so no GC either! think of those permanently-held references you thought were freed. Its not so much about memory leaks as the time taken to allocate them, occasionally dynamic memory can take a while in heavily-fragmented cases, just like a GC can take a while to collect.

Comment: There are hard real-time GC systems that offer bounded runtimes. Soft real-time GC is fairly common--Erlang uses such a GC by default and Java has a standard spec for it, though I've never used an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to c++;
but since everything is on memory; you are going to use it somehow.
so; why should a programmer avoid it?

PS:informative comments are appreciated. :)

Comment: It is possible in C++ for all allocations to be on the stack, though I've not seen that in any large system.

Comment: Or for all data to be static, or on the stack.

Comment: And for all memory to be allocated during application startup.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you could definitely use dynamic memory allocation in mission critical apps, MC apps, need not necessarily be RT Apps, they just mean they are critical for business functioning. When dynamic memory allocation constructs are used, it always essential to have large stress tests, which can display memory leaks, when real customer environment is simulated, that way you would understand the impact of dynamic memory allocation, is it had one.

Answer (score 0):

In embedded systems and life & mission critical applications, the objective is to reduce the reliance on dynamic memory allocation.  Generally, dynamic memory is needed when the number of instances cannot be determined during run-time.  For example, dynamic memory is used when obtaining input from the user.

When reading data from sensors and obtaining real-time data from other sources, dynamic memory is not used.  Many applications use a queue and retain only the current data.

The embedded systems, when using dynamic memory allocation, will have some sort of memory reclamation algorithm, whether it be Garbage Collection (GC) or the memory is consolidated upon allocation.  If there is no memory available, many multi-thread and multi-tasking systems will either force garbage collection, deletion of unnecessary variables or wait for a duration and try the allocation again.

In the event that there is absolutely no available memory (and all efforts to reclaim memory have been exhausted) it is time to refer to the requirements spec and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks  it will be very hard to write any reasonably large system without dynamic memory allocation.

But the default memory management is a general memory manager with only very limited guarantees.
If you have specific requirements then you should have written a specialized memory management library that conforms to the requirements that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is no problem with this. HOWEVER: failure of an allocation should not cause your program to fail.

This principle extends to real-time programs. A real-time `malloc` should have an upper time bound; there might be cases in which memory is simply not available in time and it has to return NULL.

Now, one might wonder why a mission-critical system can work when a memory allocation fails. This is simple: "working" is typically not a black-and-white condition. Any interesting mission-critical system has a mix of "SHALL" and "SHOULD" requirements. Dynamic memory allocation can be used when a failure to allocate memory violates a "SHOULD" requirement. E.g. "the system SHALL support 200 widgets and SHOULD support 400" - statically allocate the first 200 widgets and dynamically allocate the next 200.

Answer (score -4):

Well, you can't avoid dynamic allocation. Somehow, somewhere, your stack has to get allocated at the very least. Usually when people start to worry excessively about whether something is on the stack or the heap it's a sign they've gone a bit funny. You can have just as many or more stack related errors as heap related but you can catch the heap related ones pretty easily in testing so long as you avoid libs that use their own memory management. But then C++ is hardly the best language for this sort of app in the first place.

Comment: You can certainly avoid dynamic allocation in the fast-path of a persistant program.  That is a crucial step towards deterministic real-time behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the juvenile downmodding. dynamic allocation is certainly deterministic. You can also specific any allocation you want, including a stack implementation.

Comment: The answer doesnt necessarily provide help, it more talks about current implementation than insight into how problems from DMA can be overcome.

Comment: Did you even read what the question is? It asks if it's worth avoiding dynamic memory allocation due to being 'mission critical. The answer is, no it's not. You can completely control dynamic allocation with a private heap or series of bins. It's just as safe as using the stack if done properly. Actually safer because dynamic memory will not run out nearly as quickly as the stack.

Comment: Sorry Charles, I should revise my comment to "dynamic allocation as implemented by almost every general-purpose allocator has non-deterministic and sometimes very costly latency".  Of course if you have specific constraints you can come up with an allocation scheme that is deterministic, but that's not present in `libc.so` or `msvcrt.dll`, for example.  And FWIW, the downvotes came from someplace else, but your comment about C++ being hardly the best language seems inappropriate nonetheless.  The same question of dynamic allocation comes up in C as well.